# Error cors, problemas de seguridad

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs, api, servidor

Chicos, tengo un dilema, si fuere posible su ayuda porfa .
Tengo una base de datos oracle sql, esta tiene los datos y los usuarios

un contector de c# que toma la base de datos y la manipula (un parto de configurar)

capa logica en asp.net(c#) que toma la data de la base de datos la ordena y la envia formateada por las rutas indicadas

front-end en react.js pagina  web que uno ve, la cual solicita datos al api y los despliega , tambien le envía los datos para que los procese.

Todo bien, pero tengo un problema de seguridad,

codigo Js

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:5000',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si el problema es que supuestamente le estamos mandando solicutades desde distitnas direcciones al servidor , lo cual es extraño por que estamos desde la misma maquina, alguna seguridad bloquea el paso.

Comment: protocolo, dominio/ip y puerto deben ser iguales, sino vas a tener que definir excepciones ( que se verifican en el preflight )

Comment: Mmm no, ninguna de las 2 respuesta es, nose que sera :/ :/ :/

Answer (score 0):

Los errores de CORS son temas a tratar en el backend. ¿Tienes alguna cabecera definida en este entorno para permitir llamadas de cualquier `origin`?

Yo, por ejemplo, con ReactJS consumo una API REST programada en PHP y tengo las siguientes cabeceras en el backend:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Token');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Allow: POST');
```

Revisa que no te falte algo por el estilo.

Comment: Gracias Brother :)